# How to create a pandas.Timestamp from datetime.datetime object and nanoseconds value

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a datetime.datetime object (which has miliseconds resolution) and a nanoseconds value in a separate integer. How can I combine them into a pandas.Timestamp without going via a string representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.Timedelta` to add nanoseconds to a datetime.

Consider this example:

```
In [57]: dt = datetime.datetime(2015,8,01,9,30,15,150000)

In [58]: print dt
2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000

In [60]: pd.Timestamp(dt)
Out[60]: Timestamp('2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000')

In [62]: pd.Timestamp(dt) + pd.Timedelta(888)
Out[62]: Timestamp('2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000888')
```

This will also work on a Series of Timestamps:

```
In [63]: s = pd.Series([dt, dt])

In [64]: s
Out[64]:
0   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150
1   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [65]: s + pd.Timedelta(888)
Out[65]:
0   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000888
1   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000888
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [66]: s_nano = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(888), pd.Timedelta(999)])

In [67]: s + s_nano
Out[67]:
0   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000888
1   2015-08-01 09:30:15.150000999
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Starting from a series of integer nanoseconds, you can easily convert it to timedelta:

```
In [71]: pd.to_timedelta(s_nano, unit='ns')
Out[71]:
0   00:00:00.000000
1   00:00:00.000000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [72]: pd.to_timedelta(s_nano, unit='ns').values
Out[72]: array([888, 999], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

The reason it shows only zeros in the series repr seems a bug in pandas, as the values are correct.